# Conversion of scientific notation to long numbers using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to convert `8.9148E+19` to numeric format using **c#**

I have already tried using  `Double.Parse(3.58E+14, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)` but it is rounded up the value, but not returned the actual number.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to display as a string not in scientific notation or just do calculations?

Comment: When I tried `var a = Double.Parse("8.9148E+19", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float); Console.WriteLine(a);` I got "8.9148E+19". How did *you* look at the value?

Comment: I think you're actually talking about the formatting when converting the double to a string. If you want to show all the digits, try `double.ToString("N")` or `double.ToString("F0")` - e.g. `Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("8.9148E+19").ToString("F0"));`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Parse` from `decimal`.

```cs
var parsed = decimal.Parse("8.9148E+19", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check and convert the exponent value use this:

```
//your value
string val = "8.9148E+19";     
//create a dummy
double dummy;
//check if ist valid
bool hasExponential = (val.Contains("E") || val.Contains("e")) && double.TryParse(val, out dummy);
if (hasExponential)
{
    //if it is valid parse it
    decimal d = decimal.Parse(val, NumberStyles.Float);
}
```